# Do I need to convert to gzip format or tar format?

Tags: tar, gzip, ascii

```
$file ccache-2.4.tar.gz 
ccache-2.4.tar.gz: HTML document, ASCII text
```

The file, ccache-2.4.tar.gz is in the ASCII test format

```
 ccache-2.4.tar.gz: not in gzip format

tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

kindly provide your suggestion

Comment: You downloaded the file incorrectly. Maybe you got an authentication page, maybe you got a download page. Shows us how you downloaded the file. If you used `wget` or `curl`, try using a browser.

Comment: i have searched for the string   ccache , shows below given link                                                                                      ".https://www.samba.org/ftp/ccache/ccache-2.4.tar.gz

Answer (score 3):

The file available in https://www.samba.org/ftp/ccache/ccache-2.4.tar.gz is *really* a tar archive. Therefore, the real question is not "How do I convert it from ASCII to tar format", but "Why does the file is an ASCII file instead of a tar?"

Probably, [you downloaded the file incorrectly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399211/do-i-need-to-convert-to-gzip-format-or-tar-format/1399227#comment2425588_1399211) (and ASCII file contains the error strings returned by the server), or who gave you the file did.
Use a browser to download it or, if you want to do it by terminal, run:

```
curl -sfL "https://www.samba.org/ftp/ccache/ccache-2.4.tar.gz" -o ~/Downloads/ccache-2.4.tar.gz
```

or

```
wget -nv "https://www.samba.org/ftp/ccache/ccache-2.4.tar.gz" -O ~/Downloads/ccache-2.4.tar.gz
```

The file `ccache-2.4.tar.gz` will be downloded in your `~/Downloads` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not a tar file but ASCII you can rename the file: remove 'tar.gz"  and replace it by ".txt" with...

```
cp ccache-2.4.tar.gz ccache-2.4.txt
```

and you will be able to view the contents with "more", "less" or a text editor.

Comment: how do i convert the ASCII format to tar archive

Comment: @vignesh You don't. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1399227/653515) answer.

Comment: Renaming the file shouldn't be necessary to do that, if a file is a text-file, one should be able to open the file with a text-editor, `more` or `less` anyway, regardless of it's name.